# Is there a name for kanji which look very similar?

Tags: kanji, orthography, reading-comprehension

For example, 未 and 末.

I tried looking for 同じ見える漢字 and 同見漢字 but they didn't seem to be correct or to refer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://machigai-sagashi.com/all_list/ - there doesn't appear to be a real name but it calls them 似ている漢字

Comment: I guess that works, thank you. Nice list, too!

Comment: I didn't realize these were separate kanji until just the other day:  [柿]{かき} and [杮]{こけら}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly but [類字](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A1%9E%E5%AD%97-660317) is a close and established term for that and is found in dictionaries, although it doesn't exclude non-kanji writing systems. In practice, 類字 is mostly applied to kanji (and perhaps kana), like 同字 and 別字 are.

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One word that I've seen used some is 類似【るいじ】漢字【かんじ】.  [Googling for this phrase in Japanese](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%A1%9E%E4%BC%BC%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%22+%22%E3%81%AF%22) yields around 8.5K hits (adding "は" to the search string to filter specifically for Japanese).  The second hit in that list (for me, anyway) is [this page](https://kanji-database.sourceforge.net/variants/similar-chars.html) from a section of the SourceForge website, listing visually similar characters.  For some reason the Machigai-Sagashi website in @[Angelos](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9971/)'s comment isn't loading for me, so apologies if this other site is a dupe or similar.